# How can I type a curved arrow up in a text

Tags: arrows

I find a lot of arrows, but none of them is exactly what I want. How can I make this arrow: curved and up?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard response to questions like this is to try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). This does not seem to help in this case, so I suggest building the arrow with [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz). The OP does not say how the arrow will be used --- it would be better if the OP gave a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show exactly what is needed --- but I think that this arrow will probably be used as an operator in equations, so the arrow should be defined  using `\mathop`. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% larger choice of arrow heads

\newcommand\curvedarrow{%
\mathop{\tikz[scale=0.24]{\draw[thick,-{Triangle[scale=0.5]}]
              (0,0)to[out=0,in=270](1,1);}}%
}

\begin{document}

  $X\curvedarrow Y$

\end{document}
```

produces the arrow:

[image]

I have used a different arrow head than in the OP as this arrow head looked better to me. The two `scale` values I chose through trial and error, it should be better if these were somehow set using the line height, for example.

If the `\curvedarrow` macro is not going to be used in math-mode then its definition should be shortened to:

```
\newcommand\curvedarrow{%
    \tikz[scale=0.24]{\draw[thick,-{Triangle[scale=0.5]}]
         (0,0)to[out=0,in=270](1,1);}%
    }
```

The math-mode variant of `\curvedarrow` will not behave well with subscripts and superscripts -- but the OP did not say these were needed. If this macro is likely to be used in sub/superscripts then a `\mathpalette` variant is needed.

Comment: yes, I had already tried detexify, I even tried http://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math.html#/demo/equation but that didn't work either. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Some other options.

If you are willing to use `xelatex` or `lualatex`, you can use any font containing the appropriate Unicode character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\symbola{Symbola}
\newfontfamily\dejavuserif{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\cambria{Cambria}
\begin{document}
{\symbola\symbol{"2934}}

{\dejavuserif\symbol{"2934}}

{\cambria\symbol{"2934}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also an arrow like this defined in the `stix` package. But this requires you to change (at least) your maths fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$\uprightcurvearrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]